# Searching for content in the original language returns no results, English works fine

Tags: azure-video-indexer

When I search for a keyword in the original language of an uploaded video, I get no results, whereas if I use the translated keyword in English, results are returned correctly. Here are the steps I used:

1. Logged into Azure Video Indexer.
2. Uploaded a video whose audio is in Arabic. Made sure the correct language, Arabic, is selected.
3. Waited until indexer completed the indexing.
4. Searched for a keyword in Arabic like 'حديث', but got no results.
5. Changed the filter by selecting a language from the dropdown (I chose Arabic, which then added a tag **Language: ar-EG** to the filter.
6. Yet again, the search returned no results.
7. When searched for the translated text: Talk, which is in English, the results were returned as expected.

I haven't tried to use the API instead of the Web UI, but I think I may have made a mistake somewhere.

Did anyone face a similar issue? Or is there anything I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Video indexer team fix this issue.
You should see now the expected video when search Arabic keyword.

Comment: I confirm that this issue is resolved as of date. Thanks to all those who contributed.